# Gradle Multi-Module groovy 'Project' object not getting evaluated in helper files

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

I have a multi-module setup for a Java project with following structure.

```
mainApp
|--> core-module
|       |--> src
|       |--> build.gradle
|       |--> gradle.properties
|       
|--> lib-module
|       |--> src
|       |--> build.gradle
|       |--> gradle.properties
|--> lib-another-module
|       |--> src
|       |--> build.gradle
|       |--> gradle.properties
|--> settings.gradle
|--> build.gradle
```

And in my `settings.gradle` I've specified.

```
rootProject.name = 'mainApp'

include 'core-module'
include 'lib-module'
include 'lib-another-module'
```

in my `mainApp/build.gradle` file, I've written a helper as `helper-tasks.gradle` and imported that file in my `$rootDir/build.gradle` file as

```
apply from: "$rootDir/helpers/helper-tasks.gradle"
```

`task('bundleJar', type: Jar)` is a part of `subprojects { subproject -> }` closure and I'll be just calling `./gradlew bundleJar`. Here expectations are it should iterate through each sub-project and collect the classes for my final bundle

in `helper-tasks.gradle` file I wrote a `gradle tasks` as below

```
task('bundleJar', type: Jar) {

    manifest {
        attributes 'Manifest-Version': "1.0"
        attributes 'Built-By': USER_NAME
        attributes 'Created-By': "Java Version: " + JAVA_VERSION
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': BUNDLE_VERSION + " Build " + GIT_COMMIT_HASH
        attributes 'Build-Timestamp': BUILD_TIME
    }
    baseName('lib-module')
    from project('lib-module').sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs
}
```

Here `project('lib-module').sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs` doesn't pick-up relative path of sub-module project `$rootDir/lib-module/build/classes/java/main` but still referring to `"$rootDir/build/classes/java/main`. Why? and how can I provide my settings to helper files?

Comment: is there anyway I can provide the `project` object to my "helper-tasks.gradle" file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a working example [here on GitHub](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64555185).

Consider the `build.gradle` at the root:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/helpers/helper-tasks.gradle"
}
```

and `helpers/helper-tasks.gradle`:

```
task('bundleJar', type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Manifest-Version': "1.0"
        attributes 'Built-By': USER_NAME
        attributes 'Created-By': "Java Version: " + JAVA_VERSION
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': BUNDLE_VERSION + " Build " + GIT_COMMIT_HASH
        attributes 'Build-Timestamp': BUILD_TIME
    }
    baseName("${project.name}") 
    from project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs
}
```

Note that the name of the file now matches the project name. In the example, `gradle lib-module:bundleJar` will generate `./lib-module/build/libs/lib-module.jar` with appropriate classes.

Similarly, `gradle lib-another-module:bundleJar` will generate `./lib-another-module/build/libs/lib-another-module.jar` (with appropriate classes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I missed the part that this `task('bundleJar', type: Jar)` is a part of `subprojects { subproject -> }` closure and I'll be just calling `./gradlew bundleJar`. Here expectations are it should iterate through each sub-project and collect the classes for my final bundle